# Trigger Appsync mutation from lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, graphql, amazon-dynamodb

I keep getting this error message when I try to trigger a mutation through lambda when I *add/modify/delete* items from DynamoDB:

> "message" : "Invalid request, `query` can't be null.",

So what I am trying to do is whenever a modification is done directly on *dynamodb*, the subscribed users will be notified with the changes.

I have created the new mutation with None type data source. I tested it out directly on the query console and it works fine.

I have also created the lambda function based on Python that is able to retrieve the *dynamodb* streams and has tested it out with *cloudwatch*.

Now the issue is when I try to do a HTTP post request from the lambda, i get:

> error: MalformedHttpRequestException
>
> message: invalid request, `query` can't be null.

---

name of mutation: addTodo

the data i am sending over post:

```
{'operationName': 'addTodo',
   'variables':{'id': '400',
                'name': 'some name', 
                'description': 'some description',
                'query': 'mutation addTodo($id: ID,
                                           $name: String,
                                           $description: String)
                 {addTodo(id: $id,
                          name: $name,
                          description: $description)
                  {id name description}}'
                }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `query` inside `variables` in your payload but it's expected to be passed outside like this:

```
{
    'operationName': 'addTodo',
    'variables': {
        'id': '400',
        'name': 'some name',
        'description': 'some description'
    },
    'query': 'mutation addTodo(...'
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but the documentation still has it setup incorrectly.
https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/functions/graphql-from-lambda/q/platform/js/